# Accept only the first entry

Tags: awk

I have the data in the following format:

```
1    0001    field   field   field
2    0050    field   field   field
3    ffff    field   field   field
4    0003    field   field   field
5    0001    field   field   field
6    0004    field   field   field
7    0002    field   field   field
8    0100    field   field   field
9    wwww    field   field   field
```

I need the lines starting with $2 == "0001" and ending with $2 == "0003", namely:

```
1    0001    field   field   field
2    0050    field   field   field
3    ffff    field   field   field
4    0003    field   field   field
```

and doing it like this:

```
awk '$2 == "0001", $2 == "0003"' ./file.txt
```

But I get all lines in response, probably because "0001" besides the first line also occurs in line number five, which breaks the logic and output.

I can guess that it is necessary to specify that only first entry should be accepted. How do I do that?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how this answers my question.

Comment: Wait a sec, if you just want the first 4 lines, just use `head -n 4 file.txt`. or `awk 'NR <= 4' file.txt`

Comment: record the first occurrence of 0001, then print until you encounter 0003 `awk '$2 == "0001" {found=1}found {print} $2 == "0003" {exit}' file`

Comment: I misunderstood what you wanted, I though you were trying to prevent duplicates of `0001`.

Comment: This sounds like one of those questions where someone says "I need the first 4 lines of input" but what they really mean is "I need the lines starting with $2 == "0001" and ending with $2 == "0003" which just happen to be the first 4 lines in this specific example but in reality could be anywhere else in the input instead". Please [edit] your question to make your requirements clear.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Exactly what I need, thank you. Can you please explain the {found=1}found {print} part? I don't really understand it.

Comment: @KarlsD if that's what you think you need, it's probably not what you really need (e.g. [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77803195/accept-only-the-first-entry#comment137160908_77803195) would exit with no output if a `0003` appeared before the first `0001` as the `$2 == "0003" {exit}` is probably in the wrong place). If you [edit] your question to clarify your requirements then we can help you. Make sure to cover what to do in the cases of nested and overlapping ranges and missing start/end delimiters.

Comment: When there is a match for `$2 == "0001"` you set found to 1. AWK then evaluates the value of found (which is 1) to true and prints the whole line.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ranges.html

Comment: If you don't want to exit before encountering 0001 then you can also check for both for the exit `awk '$2 == "0001" {found=1} found {print} found && ($2 == "0003") {exit}' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remember the first occurrence of `0001` in column 2 until you encounter `0003` in column 2.

```
awk '$2 == "0001" {found=1} found; found && $2 == "0003" {exit}' file
```

After setting found to 1, check the value of found. If it is 1, it evaluates to true and prints the whole line.

If you also only want to exit if `0001` is actually found, then check for both found and if the column 2 is `0003`. If that is the case then exit.

Output

```
1    0001    field   field   field
2    0050    field   field   field
3    ffff    field   field   field
4    0003    field   field   field
```

---

Or checking for found once:

```
awk '$2 == "0001" {found=1} found {print; if($2=="0003") {exit}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution only applies if the 2nd pattern you are looking for comes after exactly four rows:

$ ugrep -K0001,0003 --max-line=4 -a ' ' file

1    0001    field   field   field

2    0050    field   field   field

3    ffff    field   field   field

4    0003    field   field   field

Unfortunately the -K option of ugrep only gives the lines before the second pattern:

$ ugrep -K0001,0003 -a ' ' file

1    0001    field   field   field

2    0050    field   field   field

3    ffff    field   field   field

ugrep -> https://github.com/Genivia/ugrep